# Proguard returned with error code 1. See console,'-jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

I cant export the android project to apk file

[2015-02-21 23:36:24 - GoMax] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-02-21 23:36:24 - GoMax] '-jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2015-02-21 23:36:24 - GoMax] operable program or batch file.

my proguard.cfg

```
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
 native <methods>;
 }

-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
 void set*(***);
 *** get*();
 }

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
 public void *(android.view.View);
 }


-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
public static <fields>;
}

-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Comment: How are you invoking Proguard?

Comment: I dont know how to resolve this , this project was created by my friend , and its running smoothly on my phone as Run this project .He is alos not reachable .
its a webview app , while exporting the apk using eclips , I got this error

Comment: Are you using a shell script to run Proguard? A gradle project? An ant file? Whichever it is, what are the instructions there for running Proguard?

Comment: pls look here [link]http://s14.postimg.org/t0kvvmvsx/ERROT.png

Comment: If that's Eclipse, look into the ant file. If that's Android Studio, look into the .gradle file. It appears to be trying to pass a `-jar` command line argument to Proguard which doesn't take such an argument. Also look into that FileNotFoundException -- it might be related to a malformed command line.

Comment: its eclips , and where can I find  .gradle file

Comment: In Eclipse, it's probably an ant *.xml file. Look through the .xml files in the project tree.